# Exit call inside spawn in erlang

Tags: erlang

I am new to Erlang and I would like to know the difference between two code snippets.

```
 spawn_link(exit(fun()-> myfun() end))
```

and

```
spawn_link(fun()->exit(myfun()) end)
```

I was thinking behaviour would be same, but it is not.

Answer (score 4):

`spawn_link` is a function, and the calls behave like normal function calls: first the arguments are evaluated, and then the function is called with the evaluated arguments.

So in the first example, the argument to `spawn_link` is:

```
exit(fun()-> myfun() end)
```

`exit`, when called with one argument, makes the current process exit, using the argument as the exit reason.  So in this case, the process crashes before it has a chance to call `spawn_link`, and never spawns a new process.  (The exit reason of the current process will be a `fun`, which is very unusual, but allowed.  The `fun` will not be called.)

In the second example, the argument to `spawn_link` is:

```
fun()->exit(myfun()) end
```

That is a `fun`. The expressions inside it are not going to be evaluated until the function is called.  Thus we're passing this function to `spawn_link`, which spawns a new process running this function.  The newly spawned process will call `myfun`, and then exit with the return value of `myfun` as its exit reason.